# maven package JDO dependencies with shade jar

Tags: maven, datanucleus, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to package a shade jar which consists of my code + dependencies. I am able to package everything fine but since I am using DataNucleus (datanucleus-core, datanucleus-api-jdo, datanucleus-rdbms) they have their plugin.xml in their root directory. I tried using the XmlAppendingTransformer that comes with shade but since the root element of these xml's is just `<plugin>` the transformer merges all the `<extension>` elements into one giant `<plugin>` tag and during runtime the DataNucleus classloader is not able to find the right plugins. So my questions are:

1) Is it a good practice to package all dependencies into 1 jar ? Or should I copy-dependencies into a folder and include that folder in the classpath during runtime ?

2) If I want to package DataNucleus with my jar, how to handle the multiple plugin.xml's ? I tried putting them in a `<plugins>` root tag but that didn't work either. Do they have to be in the root folder ? Can I move them during the shade process to a different folder ?

Answer (score 0):

All plugin.xml (Eclipse OSGi plugin) have to be in the root of the CLASSPATH, so you'd have to merge them. Similarly you'd need to merge the contents of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (OSGi Metadata).

Good practice ? I wouldn't argue one way or the other. Do what feels right for your environment and project.

If you find a way of merging them reliably, let us know so it can go in the DN docs for the benefit of those that want to do such a thing. Others have tried before, some posts on stackoverflow IIRC

Comment: well... I just ended up excluding org.datanucleus:* jars from shading. The rest is shaded. It's not a big deal for extra couple of jars in the classpath for a startup command but it looks nasty when you have like 50 jars in your classpath. That's the only reason. Some people would just prefer to have all jars in one. I prefer it myself but it's the matter of taste I believe. :)